# creating pretty url for plug in wordpress?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, wordpress

as a learner, and a new one to wordpress, i am trying to learn how to make the urls look pretty,

i have installed wordpress on my localhost, and url of wordpress appear as

> localhost/wordpress/ads/?adtitle=product-name
>
> localhost/wordpress/index.php?jobid=100&jobtitle=job-name

and i want to make it the URL looks like

> localhost/wordpress/ads/your-product-name/
>
> localhost/wordpress/100/job-name/

SO FOR SO NOW, i am trying to grab the concepts, and read different stackoverflow answer and google for it, following some [tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and googled code, What i am able to produce so for is..

```
function myruleszfr(){ 
add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');

}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'zfr_query_vars' );
function zfr_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'nutrition';
    return $query_vars;
}

     print_r(zfr_query_vars( $query_vars ));
```

as I am a learner, and i am trying to learn the process, can somebody guide me to the process that how should i modify the existing code to make my URL pretty? can some body guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this one , its really simple and nice .

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pretty-link/

Let me know if you have any query about it.

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks, definitely i can use these tool, what if i intend to code it? so that i get better and better understanding of each and every component?

Comment: @NewBee yah you can also create your own code, though you can get idea from this plugin for your own development :)